# How to add hyperlink inside ClientTemplate with IF condition- Ajax Bound Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC. I want to make the Account_Number column as HTML link in the Ajax Bound Kendo UI grid, when it is not searched by Account_Number from previous page. And when clicked on the Account_Number link, it should pass the Account_Number to the Customer controller method 'QuickCheckSearch'.
The below code does not populate the grid in view and also do not call/pass the value to the controller. Could someone please correct the following code?

Thanks in Advance.

```
  columns.Bound(p => p.Account_Number)
 .ClientTemplate("<#if (item.Account_Number == Model.AccountNumber){>Account_Number <# }" + "else{#><a href='" + Url.Action("QuickCheckSearch", "Customer") + "?Account_Number=#=Account_Number#'>#= Account_Number #</a> <# } #>")
 .Title("Account Number");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview
2. You have way too many angle brackets all over the place.  You should only have them on the actual HTML markup of the template, *not* as part of the template syntax itself.  Try:

   ```
   .ClientTemplate(
       "# if (Account_Number ==" + @Model.AccountNumber + "){ #" +
           "#= Account_Number #" +
       "# }" +
       "else { #" +
            "<a href = '" + Url.Action("QuickCheckSearch", "Customer") + "?Account_Number=#=Account_Number#'>#= Account_Number#</a>" +
       "# } #"
   )
   ```

I find it really helps to format it on separate lines just like you would write actual code instead of all on one line so you can see the structure visually.

You could also do it this way, which may be cleaner:

```
.ClientTemplate("#= accountLinkTemplate(data) #")
....
<script>
     function accountLinkTemplate(data) {
        var template = data.Account_Number;
        if (data.Account_Number == " + @Model.AccountNumber + ") {
            template = "<a href = '" + "@Url.Action("QuickCheckSearch", "Customer")" + "?Account_Number=" + data.Account_Number+ "'>" + data.Account_Number+ "</a>";
        }

        return template;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Double-check everything...I just retested the first one in a live project but with my own ViewModel, of course, and the grid is rendering and the url is properly formed.  For the second one, I just edited my answer with a corrected template.

Comment: Sorry about answering, as it did not allow me to paste the code in comment.
I'm getting the url now but the Account_Number value is not being passed to controller method in both cases yet.

Comment: You aren't getting the ID because you are formatting the url with "Account_Number=" but your controller action is accepting a parameter with the name "AccountNumber".  The name of your server parameter *must* match the name you are using in the url.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
It worked. Changed "?Account_Number" to "?AccountNumber" . Also while comparing the strings inside script, had to use   

var modelAccountNumber = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.AccountNumber));

         if (data.Account_Number ==  modelAccountNumber) { ..... }

Comment: I have another question with anchor tag. On click of a "View" link, I would want an image to be displayed in a modal popup.  How to achieve this ? Here is the code which is not actually calling js function: columns.Template(p => p.ViewCheckImage).ClientTemplate(
                                "# if (ViewCheckImage == true) {# " +
                                "<a  onclick=\"onDeferredCheckImageSelection('#=data#')\">View</a>" +
                                "#}" + "else { # Not Available# } #")
                            .Title("Check Image");